# memory of a process in Lua

Tags: lua

How can I get the meomory of any Process in Lua?

Is it possible in Lua? Is C# it is possible but I am not sure.

In C# we can use PerformanceCounter class to get the

```
PerformanceCounter WorkingSetMemoryCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process",
    "Working Set", ReqProcess.ProcessName);
```

What is equivalent of this in Lua?

Suppose there are 5 process of IE (Internet Explorer) running . How to get a List of those process?

Comment: It's Lua. Lua is not an acronym.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on what others have said, Lua is a scripting language designed for embedding. That means that it runs *inside* another application.

`Lua.exe` is one such application. But it is not the only application that Lua scripts can be written to be executed on.

When within a Lua script, you have access to exactly and *only* what the surrounding application environment allows. If the application does not explicitly allow you to access things like "files" or "the operating system", then you don't get to access them. Period.

Lua's standard library (which an application can forbid scripts to use. Lua.exe allows it, but there are some embedded environments that do not) is very small. It doesn't offer a lot of amenities, which make Lua ideal for embedded environments: small standard libraries mean smaller executables. Which is why you see a lot more Lua in mobile applications than, say, Python. Also, the standard library is cross-platform, so it does not access platform-specific libraries.

Modules, user-written programs (either in Lua or C/C++) can be loaded into Lua.exe's environment. Such a module could give your Lua script access to things like "processes", how much memory the process is taking, and so forth. But if you do not have access to such a module, then you're not getting that info from within a Lua script.

The most you are going to be able to do is get the size of the memory that this particular Lua environment is directly allocating and using, as @lhf said: `collectgarbage "count"`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the memory allocated by Lua in Kbytes, use `collectgarbage"count"`.

Answer (score 0):

Lua does not comes with this built-in functionality. You could write a binding to a library that provides you that or you could interface with a program to do that (like reading the output of "ps -aux | grep firefox").